# If $p$ and $q=10p+1$ are odd primes, show that $(p/q)=(-1/p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\def\leg#1#2{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)}$ If $p$ and $q=10p+1$ are odd primes, show that $\leg pq=\leg{-1}{p}$

I was trying two cases where $p= 3 \pmod 4$ and $p=1\pmod 4$

If $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4, \leg pq= -\leg qp  = -\leg{10p+1}{p} =\leg{-1}{p}$   (Did I do this right?)

But if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4, \leg pq=\leg qp = \leg{10p+1}{p} = \leg1p$

Since I'm trying to get $\leg{-1}{p}$ as an answer, I'm doing something wrong...any suggestions?

Comment: Does (p/q) represent the Legendre symbol?

Comment: yes, (p/q) reps the Legendre symbol

Comment: I began editing but got tired. @Kara, please do try to use LaTeX to write mathematics here.

Comment: The -1 appears only if [both primes are congruent to 3 mod 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Legendre.27s_version_of_quadratic_reciprocity).

Comment: This is a fairly direct application of quadratic reciprocity...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What I've tried is written above, I'm not sure that its the correct way to go about the problem though

Answer (score 3):

The step you are missing is that $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ implies $(\frac{-1}p)=1=(\frac{1}p)$